# using BotUI with meteor.js

Tags: meteor, npm

I'm trying to use the [BotUI framework](https://github.com/botui/botui) in my meteor project and following the [installation guide](https://docs.botui.org/install.html), but can't seem to get it to work. No matter which setup I try, I always get various errors, for the following I get `Uncaught TypeError: BotUI is not a constructor`.

**My client/main.js file:**

```
//import Meteor stuff
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';
import { ReactiveVar } from 'meteor/reactive-var';

//NPM packages
import Vue from 'vue'; //not necessary according to installation guide
import BotUI from 'botui';

//files
import './main.html';


Meteor.startup(() => {

    var botui = new BotUI('my-botui-app');

    botui.message.bot({
        content: "Hello there!"
    });

});
```

**My client/main.html file:**

```
<head>
    <title>BotUI with Meteor</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Welcome to Meteor!</h1>

    <div id="my-botui-app">
        <bot-ui>     
        </bot-ui>
    </div>
</body>
```

I also tried including the files locally in `/imports` or using CDN with `$.getScript`, but with no success.

What am I missing?

Comment: can you writing code outside `Meteor.startup()` and also add a class on UI like `<div class="botui-app-container" id="my-botui-app">`

Comment: @AnkurSoni still no change, I get the same error

Comment: did you add a package in the meteor, using `npm install botui --save`, if yes then try to create new file `botui.js` and then import it in `main.js`. `main.js` is not able to identify the imports.

Comment: kind of made it better (at least it's a new error): ```Uncaught Error: BotUI: Element with id #my-botui-app does not exist```
From what I read, I thought meteor always loads html files first - how can the script not know the element?

Comment: add `<template>` in HTML code, import this template in your js file, then write the `var botui = new BotUI('my-botui-app');` in js file and write code `botui.message.bot({
        content: "Hello there!"
    });` inside `Template.onRendered()`. This should solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

For people who will encounter the "BotUI is not a constructor" issue in the future, this is related to missing scripts and css in the index.html, and recommended to flow the BotUi instructions.